# I cannot refresh my Youtube API token and I don't understand the error returned

Tags: php, curl, google-api, youtube-api

I'm new here and I thank in advance everyone that will help me.

I use Youtube API to collect comments in some videos. That's really important for me, because I have a system developed in PHP that collects public content of social media. I have an app in Google APIs and I can authenticate the account on my system using OAUTH. It works just fine.

However, this token expires after a few minutes. There is something in the API called refresh token, which is returned after the first authentication. It must be used exactly to refresh my token and keep me accessing the API. Some days ago this resource stopped working. I'm not able to refresh my token anymore and I don't understand the error in the JSON they return to me.

I try to renew the token using cUrl:

```
public function renewToken() {
    $url = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token';
    $params = array(
        'body' => array(
            'client_id' => self::CLIENT_ID, 
            'client_secret' => self::CLIENT_SECRET, 
            'refresh_token' => $this->refresh_token, 
            'grant_type' => 'refresh_token',
        ), 
    );

    $return = $this->curl->post($url, $params);
    if($this->curl->http_code==200)
        ....
```

It was working until one or two weeks ago. Then it just stopped I can't seem to find why. The only error message returned by the API says:

```
{
  "error" : "invalid_request"
}
```

I created a new application on Google APIs Console, got the client ID and secret and the Key, changed them in my code and the result is the same. I have the faintest clue of what if going on. Is it happening to somebody

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [OAuth2.0 documentation on Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer) was last changed 2 days ago (as of today, October 8th, 2016), on October 6th (see bottom of page). I can only assume that they recently made some changes to the workflow, which would explain why your app stopped working all of a sudden.

I noticed, for example, that the documented URL for renewing the token is not `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token`, as used by you, but rather `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token` (see section "Using a refresh token"). Please try with this URL.